# Abort the loading of a shared library from its initializer

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, abort, initializer

I have a shared library that sets up shared memory in its initializer.
When I can't allocate the shared memory, I would like to abort the loading of this library by the calling program, so that this program's load will fail and can act accordingly.

I am using QLibrary.isloaded() to check if the library is loaded in the calling program.

How can I prevent the library from being loaded when an error in the initializer occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention Qt, perhaps using [QPluginLoader](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qpluginloader.html) is better. Read more about [Qt Plugins](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/plugins-howto.html) and make your plugin return a pointer to a QObject, which would be NULL to indicate failure.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
I would like to know the answer to my question anyway though ;)